# Extract data from html code with VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm looking to extract the value "Round 38" from the below html code, using VBA.

```
<tr class="event_round"><td colspan="6">Round 38</td></tr>
<tr id="g_1_Sxbhvay8" class="odd stage-finished" style="cursor: pointer;"><td class="cell_ib icons left">
```

Could anyone give me a hint?

Below you could find a part of my code:

```
    Set tRows = mTbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    With dictObj
        For Each tRow In tRows
            tRowID = tRow.ID
            If Not .Exists(tRowID) Then
                .add tRowID, Empty
            End If
        Next tRow
    End With
```

Comment: does `tRow.InnerHtml` or `tRow.InnerText` work?

Comment: try `td` instead of `tr` in `Set tRows ...`

Comment: 'tRow.innerText' it works. Thank you both!